# how to use google material icons as class instead of <i> tag

Tags: google-material-icons

According to the guideline in the [Google Material website](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) we have to use material icons in  _**i** _   tag.

the question is how to add the icons as font-awesome. something like :

`Class="material-icons face"`

instead of

`<i class="material-icons"> face </i>`

Comment: I know this is 4 years ago and that my answer is a bit out of topic (since it doesn't use a `class` attribute) but just in case it will help anyone in the future, here it goes. If you just replace `<i>` with `<span>`, it works. For example, `<span class="material-icons"> face </span>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes,you can add the material icons as classes using the after pseudo elements.check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdrqvega/)

```
 <span class="material-icons face"></span>

.face {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.face:after {
    content: "face";
}
```

Answer (score 12):

There's an easier way than the accepted answer. I got inspiration for this from the plugin css-toolip, which utilises the `attr()` css function (surprisingly has high browser adoption).

> While attr() is supported for effectively all browsers for the content property...
>   https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20attr

```
<span class="material-icons" data-icon="face"></span>

.material-icons:after {
    content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

This means that you don't have to add css for each icon that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app) (an outstanding free tool to generate fonts). Set class, prefix/suffix etc to adjust then you can easily add icons by `<i class="m-home"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to create the selectors with Sass, if someone don't want to use data selectors.

```
$icons: "content_paste_search", "format-size", "search";

@each $icon in $icons {
  .material-icons-#{$icon}:after {
    content: $icon;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="material-icons material-icons-search"></span>
```