# How to hide icon fonts in search engine results?

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, seo

My text used in html to display icons from an icon font are appearing in google search results. How can I stop this from happening?

I have already added `area-hidden` and `role='img'`, but these do not seem to have any impact.

```
<span class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true" role="img">search</span>
```

I have looked around online and mostly found information on how to improve for accessibility purposes, but not so much on how to hide it from googlebot.

### Solution

Based on @jake's answer below I went with the following.

HTML

```
<span class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true" role="img" data-icon="search"></span>
```

CSS

```
.material-icons::after{
    content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

Comment: What's the statue of your issue ? Have you found a solution ? Have you checked out my answer ?

Comment: Sorry, I put this on hold, but your answer is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281861/how-to-use-google-material-icons-as-class-instead-of-i-tag) offers an anwser in the form of pseudo elements.

On this github thread, they recommend using the font codepoint :

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/498

Check the [mapping](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints) between codepoints and icons.

Comment: Thanks, I went with your first suggestion as it does not additional data to my application.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you a bit ;)