# Get second class name inside selector of the first class name of an element

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, google-material-icons

So I was trying to use Material Icons from Google with class names instead of content inside `<i>` or `<span>`.

I found a solution in [how to use google material icons as class instead of <i> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281861/how-to-use-google-material-icons-as-class-instead-of-i-tag), but then I realized that what I really wanted to achieve was to use this for **all** material icons defined in my page, so I am looking for a **generic solution**.

I thought about something like the following.

Having:

```
<i class="material-icons foo"></i>
```

Where `foo` is whatever icon name.

I want to achieve something like:

```
.material-icons:after {
    content: "foo"
}
```

This way I could use this generic CSS rule for using **all**  material icons by class name.

So the question is:

Is there any way using CSS (or sass) to get the `"foo"` second class inside selector of `"material-icons"` first class of the `<i>` element?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the CSS content property with a Google Material Icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194077/how-to-set-the-css-content-property-with-a-google-material-icon)

Comment: That question doesn't answer what I'm looking for actually...look that what I want is to have a **generic** CSS way to get the second class of a material-icons element, where this second class is, in fact, the icon name.